# Cannot find compress while compressing build in angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular12

I'm trying to compress the build using this command

```
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist
```

i have installed `gzipper` when i run this command i get error

> Cannot find compress ..